# How can I represent a boolean on a join table to get it updated using DRF's HTML Form?

Tags: django-rest-framework

With these models:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='OrganizationUser')

class OrganizationUser(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['organization', 'user']]

    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="organizations")
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can I create a serializer for assigning users to an organization AND allow the is_admin value to be set per user?

I was trying to do this directly against the organization, but would it be more RESTful to edit each organization-user directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up exposing the join table, `OrganizationUser` in this case, directly;  creating a `ModelViewSet` for this table lets API users edit the join table directly.